# Scroll UICollectionView to section header view

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview

The code below scrolls to the right cell in `UICollectionView`, but the section header view is hidden behind `UINavigationBar` in my case. I believe I should use `scrollRectToVisible` instead and my question is, what is the right way to calculate the `CGRect` (y position) when the `numberOfRows` in a given `section` is variable.

```
- (void)scrollToPricing:(NSUInteger)row {

    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:
      [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 
                          inSection:row] 
                   atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop 
                           animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes, I am using autolayout.

Comment: just remove and then check the same thing is happen?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean. I am looking for a way to calculate content offset for given section header view Y origin position or any other way to scroll collection view in code to a header view and not the cell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this may help you

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self.collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then you can access the location through `attributes.frame`

Comment: I have more sections and based on the taps on the menu on left side of collection view I need to scroll to the desired section to the top of the collection view. I need to get headerOffset in this [self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, headerOffset, self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

Comment: means you have multiple section and you want to scroll at perticular section?

Comment: this is exactly whay I need

Comment: then this scrollToItemAtIndexPath method is right it is not working?

Comment: Read the question. It is working, but when used, it scrolls to the item. Not the top edge of the section header view of the item. I basically need to scroll to the point above the first item in a section minus the header height.

Comment: I am on collectionView, can't see rectForHeaderInSection on this class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48706/discussion-between-sunny-shah-and-martin-koles)

Comment: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self.collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; then use attributes.frame

Comment: Will try an hour from now. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, it's working well. Thanks a lot. Please update the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 36):

Seems like all the answers are overly complex. This works for me:

```
let attributes = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section))

self.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, attributes!.frame.origin.y - self.collectionView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
```

Swift 3:

```
if let attributes = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)) {
    collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: attributes.frame.origin.y - collectionView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This works well. It would be best to guard let the attributes to avoid a potential crash.

Answer (score 11):

Based on `@pixelfreak` answer

### `Swift 4.2` + `iOS 11 Safe Area` SUPPORT (for iPhone X and above)

```
if let attributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)) {
    var offsetY = attributes.frame.origin.y - collectionView.contentInset.top
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        offsetY -= collectionView.safeAreaInsets.top
    }
    collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: offsetY), animated: true) // or animated: false
}
```

> HAPPY CODING

Answer (score 5):

First, get the frame for the header in the section:

```
- (CGRect)frameForHeaderForSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:section];
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self.collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect frameForFirstCell = attributes.frame;
    CGFloat headerHeight = [self collectionView:_collectionView layout:_layout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:section].height;
    return CGRectOffset(frameForFirstCell, 0, -headerHeight);
}
```

Note: I just put a value of `1` for the `indexPath.item`. You might need to change this to something appropriate for your implementation.

Then, scroll the `UIScrollView` to the point at the top of the header:

```
- (void)scrollToTopOfSection:(NSInteger)section animated:(BOOL)animated {
    CGRect headerRect = [self frameForHeaderForSection:section];
    CGPoint topOfHeader = CGPointMake(0, headerRect.origin.y - _collectionView.contentInset.top);
    [_collectionView setContentOffset:topOfHeader animated:animated];
}
```

Note: you must subtract the `contentInset`, otherwise it will be discarded and your scrollview will scroll behind the status bar and/or navigation bar.

Answer (score 2):

```
// [myCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:index_of_sec] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

Below code will fix your problem, as i have faced same issue and used this solution developed by me instead of above commented code.

UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [myCollectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:index_of_sec]];
        CGRect rect = attributes.frame;
        [myCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(myCollectionView.frame.origin.x, rect.origin.y - HEIGHT_OF_YOUR_HEADER) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the **section header** `frame.origin.x` and `frame.origin.y` and then add up **section header** `height` with the **item** `height` to create a `CGRect` to scroll to.

```
let sectionHeaderAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: scrollToIndexPath)!;
let itemAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: scrollToIndexPath)!;

let combinedFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: sectionHeaderAttributes.frame.origin.x, y: sectionHeaderAttributes.frame.origin.y, width: sectionHeaderAttributes.frame.width, height: sectionHeaderAttributes.frame.height + itemAttributes.frame.height);

collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(combinedFrame, animated: false);
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me! Other solutions have had offset issues like items aligning with the edge of the device until the user manually scrolls, or the last few sections appearing at the top of the screen. This produced the exact effect I wanted. The only difference I made was swapping the names of sectionHeaderAttributes and itemAttributes to match the function names, but kept the combinedFrame the same.

Comment: This works the best for me too. It puts the header section at the right offset so that there's no additional automatic scrolling when the user interacts on tvOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
// scroll to selected index
NSIndexPath* cellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:sectionIndex];
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attr = [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader atIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
UIEdgeInsets insets = self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets;

CGRect rect = attr.frame;
rect.size = self.collectionView.frame.size;
rect.size.height -= insets.top + insets.bottom;
CGFloat offset = (rect.origin.y + rect.size.height) - self.collectionView.contentSize.height;
if ( offset > 0.0 ) rect = CGRectOffset(rect, 0, -offset);

[self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the accepted answer no longer works properly (2 headers sticking together), especially when the collection view has to be scrolled up (down still works fine).

The following code works perfectly in either direction:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *headerAttribs = [iconsCV layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader atIndexPath:indexPath];
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribs = [iconsCV layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGPoint topOfHeader = CGPointMake(0, attribs.frame.origin.y -collectionV.contentInset.top -headerAttribs.bounds.size.height);
[collectionV setContentOffset:topOfHeader animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue initially until I realized that the `UICollectionView.ScrollPosition` can be used to position the header in the collection view frame.

You just have to use the UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically option for the header to be visible at the center of the collection view frame.

Here's how I have achieved this in Swift 4.2:

```
let scrollableSection = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: indexPath.item)

emojiCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: scrollableSection, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
```